# floats on a matrix colors red to green

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib

I have a list of floats ranging from 0.01 to 1.0. I am assigning them to particular points on a matrix. At the moment when I assign them to a point, they cover the whole color spectrum 1.0 being black to white being 0. How can I make it so they only cover green and red.

```
    for x, y in arr_bool3:
            zeros_and_ones[x, y] = confindencenumbers[count]##set so binary matrix knows where to plot
        count=count+1


    ax.imshow((zeros_and_ones), cmap=plt.cm.spectral_r, interpolation='none') ##Draw matrix
```

arr_bool3 being the list of coordinates and confindencenumbers being the list of floats

Answer (score 1):

You could always [build your own](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps) color map using [`LinearSegmentedColormap`](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap)

```
import pylab as plt
cdict = {'red': ((0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
                 (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
         'green': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                   (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)),
         'blue': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                  (1.0, 0.0, 0.0))}

my_cmap = plt.matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('my_colormap',cdict,256)
plt.pcolor(plt.rand(10,10),cmap=my_cmap)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a single float (which implies "gray scale"), follow the instructions in this link: http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html

As you can see, you get "colors" (rather than grays) by specifying RGB tuples. By setting the B attribute to zero, you get just reds and greens. If you want to convert a value `myValue` from 0=red to 1=green, then do

```
red = 1 - myValue
green = myValue
blue = 0
```

You can figure it out from here I'm sure.